# Percent encoding output incorrect in Swift 4 for '(apostrophe)

Tags: ios, swift, urlencode

I am encoding my string to hit a web service. I am using **addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet)** to encode my String.

Everything works fine except the **'(apostrophe)** character gets encoded to **%E2%80%99** instead of **%27**.

```
    if let _keyword = keyword?
        .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
        parameters?["keyword"] = _keyword
    }
```

For Example:

> When keyword is Maggie's, output = "Maggie%E2%80%99s" instead of "Maggie%27s".
>
> Output is fine for others, when keyword is Jelly Extracts output is "Jelly%20Extracts".

So, how do I encode **'(apostrophe)** properly to **%27**

Edit: When I pass static text, like **"Maggie's.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)"** output is correct but when I wrap it in a variable output comes incorrect.

Comment: apostrophe(') is a legal character in query. It needn't not or won't be encoded.

Comment: For anyone running into this issue because apostrophe encoding doesn't work as expected, you're probably running into Smart Punctuation issues. Smart Punctuation replaces the symbol backtick (') with the apostrophe (’), which are two different characters. The apostrphe (’) encodes to %E2%80%99 whereas the symbol backtick encodes to %27.

You can turn smart punctuation off on a per textfield basis via the `smartQuotesType` method.

Comment: @AlexSullivan is correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `urlQueryAllowed` use `alphanumerics`.

```
let originalString = "Maggie's"
let escapedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
print(escapedString) // Optional("Maggie%27s")
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: It works. I check it in Playgrounds.

Comment: `let data = keyword!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
                  let test = "Uday's".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)`

Works fine when I pass static test but fails when I pass it in a variable

Comment: I set keyword as `let keyword: String? = "Uday's"` and it works well.